# How does Enumerable#sum avoid floating point rounding errors?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, floating-point, ieee-754, enumerable

I was playing around with some toy examples of floating point rounding errors in Ruby, and I noticed the following behaviour which surprised me.

First, an unsurprising example, where the rounding error occurs:

```
numbers = Array.new(10, 0.1)
#=> [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]

numbers.inject(0, :+)
#=> 0.9999999999999999
```

Now try the same with `Enumerable#sum`:

```
numbers.sum
#=> 1.0
```

The only thing I could find in the documentation that would hint at an explanation is

> sum method may not respect method redefinition of “+” methods such as Integer#+.

so I suppose there's some kind of native code implementation in place to speed up things, but I would assume C floating points are also subject to IEEE-754 related imprecise arithmetic.

What is the reason for the behaviour in the second example? How is the `sum` method able to avoid the rounding error?

Comment: A comment in the [`sum` source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/4ea5c5610aeadecf78fdd2b7d6faad8574953620/enum.c#L3898) points to [A Generalized Kahan-Babuška-Summation-Algorithm](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00607-005-0139-x), which explains why `sum` is more accurate.

Comment: That must be the answer. Thank you!

Trying to search for the term led me to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm which explains the general principle well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Amadan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/240443/amadan) gave the answer in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57394493/how-does-enumerablesum-avoid-floating-point-rounding-errors#comment101270891_57394493).

For floating point values `Enumerable#sum` uses an algorithm that compensates for the accumulation of error as the summation progresses.

As mentioned in the comment, the source code links to [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00607-005-0139-x) and Wikipedia has an article on a variation of the described algorithm known as the [Kahan Summation Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).